# Get current instance and trigger onchange in onselectall event of bootstrap multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using bootstrap [multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) library. I need to get current instance and trigger onchange in onselectall event. How can I do this ?

```
$('.binding.list').multiselect({
            onSelectAll: function (checked) {
                var $t = ... // get current instance like $(this).select
                $t.trigger('change'); // triggering onchange event
            },
            onChange: function (element) {
                var $t = $(element).parent('select'),
                    data = {};

                var values = $t.find('option:selected').map(function (i, opt) {
                    return $(opt).val();
                }).toArray().join(',');

                data["values"] = values;
                data["parameterName"] = $t.closest('tr').data('parametername');

                postRemoteWithAlways(bindingDefaultValueListOnChangeRemote, data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: When you select `Select All` - the change event will automatically get called. Why do you need to trigger it?

Comment: Are you sure ? It didn't get called. When I select one by one, change event worked but not worked for select all.